# Estimate the sum of expansions for fractional part function

Tags: number-theory, fourier-series, upper-lower-bounds

Are there any estimates for the sum of Fourier series expansions for [fractional part function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)?:
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{x=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi k \frac{n}{x})}{k}, \; n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. According to the article linked in your question,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi k \frac{n}{x})}{k}=
\begin{cases}
\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left\{\frac{n}{x}\right\}\right),&\mathrm{if}\,x\nmid n, \\
0,&\mathrm{if}\,x\mid n.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{x=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi k \frac{n}{x})}{k}=
\sum_{x=1,\, x\nmid n}^{n}\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\left\{\frac{n}{x}\right\}\right).
$$